# Statistics - Binomial and Poisson Distribution Problem

Tags: poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, poisson-process

I am given:

- I get 11 text messages per hour according to a Poisson process.
- The probability that a given text message is from my mother is $0.62$.

I then have to find the probability that I receive exactly two text messages from my mother in a 40 minute period.

My thought process is:

- Find the expected number, $E(X)$, of text messages in a 40 minute period.
- Use this value as the number of trials, $n$, in a binomial distribution to calculate $P(Y = 2)$ where $Y =$ *"the number of text messages I receive from my mother in a 40 minute period"*.

However, $E(X) = 11 \cdot \frac{40}{60} = \frac{22}{3}$ meaning my idea won't work without rounding the number of trials - giving two wildly different answers (as expected). Am I meant to round up or down, or am I doing this completely wrong? I did try averaging the probabilities of the two answers I obtained, but I'm not sure if this is correct either.

Comment: Please do not delete your questions immediately after getting an answer.  This is rude to the person who took the time to answer the question, rude to future readers who might find value in the question and answer.

Answer (score -1):

If the probability that a given text message is from my mother is independent from other text messages, you can split the poisson process: you can say that the stream of messages from my mother is a poisson process too with rate $0.62 \cdot 11 = 6.82$. This is known as 'splitting'.

The number of text messages in a 40 minute interval follows a poisson distribution with parameter $6.82 \cdot 40/60 = 341/75$. The probability that I receive exactly two text messages from my mother in a 40 minute period is:
$$\frac{e^{-341/75} (341/72)^2}{2!} \approx 0.12.$$